# How to bold inside makecell?

Tags: tables, text, makecell

I am using makecell for table cell,

```
\makecell[ct] {Power \\ Profile}
```

Now, I need to bold the content and hence I used,

```
\makecell[ct] {\textbf{Power \\ Profile}}
```

But its not compiling. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Did you already try with \bfseries Power \\ Profile

Comment: @leandriis yes, but it only making bold `Power` not `Power Profile` :(

Comment: When I tried with `\bfseries {Power \\ Profile}` it does not compile

Comment: However, when I used `\bfseries Power \\ \bfseries Profile`  it worked but looks not a good approach to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `\bfseries` placed before `\makecell`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\bfseries\makecell[ct]{Power \\ Profile}\\
non bold entry
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not simply use `\thead` with `\renewcommad\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}` in preamble?

Answer (score 1):

It also work when using `\textbf{}` to include `\makecell{}`, like this:

`\textbf{\makecell{Power \\ Profile}}`

(edited)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your answer has a tipo. Correct is `\textbf{\makecell{ ...}`. However, in spirit of `makecell` package the simplest and the most consistent solution is suggested in comment below @leandriis answer.